# 2TB Hard Drive acting as 500GB Hard Drive after Clonezilla - Partition Cloning

Tags: boot, partitioning, disk, clonezilla

I had a running System Ubuntu 16.04 with 500GB Hard Drive that I cloned to 2TB Hard Drive using Clonezila - Partition Cloning. Everything is working very fine but When  I checked Root Partition Properties it still shows 500GB but in **Disks** it shows full 2TB.

is there anything I am missing ? As per my knowledge I have to run **GPARTED** Software only when Disks shows some unallocated space. But in this case I am not sure.

For your understanding I am attaching Both Images.

[image: disks shows 2TB Partition]

[image: shows 500gb instead 2tb]

When I click in Root Folder and open Properties it shows 500GB

Comment: First problem... assuming that you have a UEFI computer, you should format the 2T disk using a GPT partition table... not MBR, as you have done. Second, when you clone a disk/partition, the clone takes on all of the parameters of the original... including size, and possibly the UUID. You need to use `gparted` to resize the partition, and assign a new UUID.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you are missing something: Cloning clones the partition *including the boundaries*.

So you now have a partition of 500Gb on a 2TB disk. That can be 2 things:

1. you have 1.5 unallocated.
2. you have 1.5 allocated to another partition.

In either case: use gparted to enlarge the 500Gb to include the extra 1.5Tb or make and use the other 1.5Tb as another partition.

1 extra comment: cloning also copies the UUID. That is going to go bad if you use both disks in the same machine. Gparted can fix that: Pick the new UUID option and apply.

> As per my knowledge I have to run GPARTED Software only when Disks shows some unallocated space.

Or to merge, shrink or enlarge partitions.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have added Images of Disks utility and Properties. And in Disks Utility there isn't any other partition.

Comment: You forgot to note the MBR partition table on the 2T HDD.